# How to fix padding being added to css grid element automatically as one side of the grid start increasing more than the other side

Tags: php, css, mysql, grid

Please am new in computer programming and am using php to develop a music website but i ran into a problem to keep occuring in different project that i have being building.
The problem is when ever am using a grid system either a css grid or a bootstrap grid system the grid keeps breaking due to padding to keeps adding automatically to any side of the grid as i uses the foreach loop to loop over many element on any side of the grid layout, this problem will always occur as far as one side of the grid has my content than the other side like maybe my side bar has many content that the main grid content vice versa ... please i don't know what to do, am using a css grid right now.. here are some screeen shot of how it will look..
enter image description here
[image]

Here is a sample of how i use my foreach loop to display many content from my database.

```
  <?php $post = new media_data();
    $posts = $post->get_posts(5);

    $num_rows = $posts->num_rows;
    
    echo '
    <div class="show-slide-container">

        <?php foreach ($posts as $no => $post) { 
        
            <div class="my-slides fade">
                <div class="txt-number-sl">
                    <?php  $no + 1 ?> / <?php  $num_rows ?>
                </div>
                <a href="<?php  'single_posts.php?post-slug=' . $post['slug'] ?>">
                    <img class="img-sl" src="<?php 'static/images/' . $post['image']; ?>"
                         alt="<?php  html_entity_decode(substrwords($post['title'], 230)); ?>">
                </a>
                <div class="txt-body-sl">
                    <?php  html_entity_decode(substrwords($post['title'], 100)); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            '
         } ?>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly maybe you should try adding `vertical-align: top` to both the divisions.

Comment: OK let me see if it will work

Comment: But i don't know why my own case is different is like am not doing something right, this seems like a unique problem that only me has ran into

Comment: In that case, it would be better if you share the full rendered HTML.

Comment: OK like the full html page right? when you said rendered html page do you mean the full html page?

Comment: Yes, the full HTML document.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219027/discussion-between-gilbert-monday-and-n3r4zzurr0).